# escaping filename in for shell command

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I'm writing C++ code, which generates a shell script that creates directories and copies files to them. The file/directory name could be assembled from any possible allowed characters. I need to escape those file/directory names. I need the script to be readable by humans, so I would like to use as little escapes and even quotes as possible. For instance:

```
mkdir \a\b\c
```

or

```
mkdir 'abc'
```

is worse than

```
mkdir abc
```

The directory/filename can even contain \n, \r and \t characters. I haven't figured out how to create a file of such a name from the command-line.

Could you please help me to wrie "mkdir_command" function?

```
std::string mkdir_command(const char * buf, size_t size) {
    // Buf can contain anything! 
    // It generates "mkdir ..." command which can be used in a shell script.
    // The function throws only in case there is a character ...
    // ... which is not allowed in the directory name, like '/' or 0.
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for which [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) is not usable?

Comment: yes, there is a reason for that

Comment: mkdir "$(printf 'foo\nbar\rand\tother\bstrange characters')" is the simplest portable way I know.  I'd ask on unix.se, I think the shell specialists are more common there.  There seems to have multiple questions there about handling those kind of files, but not how to create them.

Comment: You need to know what shell you're targeting, and know what character it deems as "special" and needs to be escaped. And then you need to iterate over your path, recognizing these special characters and add them to the output string with escapes. All other characters are added to the output string as-is.

Comment: I am not a C++ programmer, i just know the basics. I searched around for raw strings, and noticed there is an implementation of those for C++. Wouldn't it help? Maybe someone with a bit more expertise would give a better reply.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos. raw strings is a C++ features allowing to avoid escaping in string literals. Here we have two problems, first knowing what to generate so that it is correctly escaped for shell (and for that I don't feel confident that my proposition is the best), then generate it in C++ (for that we can help the OP if they have specific issues).